# Firefox language pack Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: firefox, language-support

[image]Last Firefox update 61.0b7 is in English instead of French.
I checked inside synaptic and Firefox local fr language package is installed.

How can I switch to French instead of English ?

Addons page says French language could not be verified and has been disable !!!
the French package was updated yesterday !

Comment: In _Add-ons -> Languages_ I see: "Français Language Pack could not be verified for use in Firefox. Proceed with caution." (The warning is shown for all my language packs.) So there appears to be something odd, but for me it's enabled and works. What happens if you try to enable the French language pack manually? Also, I noticed [this related bug](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1770779).

Comment: I can't see any option to enable the french pack manually ? On your link, same issue as me but firefox 60 and spanish la,gage pack. I sent a request to Mozilla facebook account yesterday, no replies received yet.

Comment: If you go to _Add-ons -> Languages_, don't you see an "Enable" button at each listed language pack?

Comment: no enable button, all is greyed out and is is written disabled by Mozilla.

Comment: I added a screenshot

Comment: I see. I'm wondering about the version number you mentioned. The version I'm using (.deb file from the Ubuntu archive) is `60.0.1build2`. From where did you get `61.0b7`? Is it possibly the Firefox snap?

Comment: How did you install Firefox *Beta*? The language packs should still work with the *stable* Firefox releases shipped by Canonical through the package manager.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem,

for me this solved the problem:
[Firefox support for signing Addons](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/add-on-signing-in-firefox?as=u#w_what-are-my-options-if-i-want-to-use-an-unsigned-add-on-advanced-users)

or in short: set `extensions.langpacks.signatures.required` to false in about:config.

Be aware that this is a security risk because this will disable the signature check for all language packs (not normal addons tho).